# Laravel installation problem (by using composer on windows)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to install laravel on windows by using composer, and got this error:
"[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/laravel/laravel.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9999: Connection refused"

Answer (score 0):

You could also run this command on the CLI before installing any dependencies. It forces the composer to use HTTPS to download all resources:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Or if your problem is not resolved:

The issue could be caused by the redirect from `http` to `https`. (or your firewall blocking the call)

According to this article, the problem could be solved by adding the following to your `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer", 
        "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
]
```

FMI: http://codinginharmony.blogspot.com/2012/10/forcing-composer-to-use-https.html#comment-form